# Meaning of 'theirs' and 'mine' in unshelve conflict

Tags: tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution, shelving

For partitioning a bigger commit into compilable portions, I decided
to shelve<sup>[1]</sup>  all files but one unit (say `A.cpp` and `A.h`).

To get rid of trivial errors in a related file (say `R.cpp`) that was also shelved, I made a few changes to it. After fixing the errors, I committed the first portion, including the minor changes
in `R.cpp`.

I unshelved the remaining files as to get the next portion done. I got a file conflict in `R.cpp` that I expected to be resolved by one click.

There are these options:

- Resolve conflict using 'theirs'
- Resolve conflict using 'mine'

TortoiseSVN explains *mine* as uncommitted changes in my working copy and *theirs* as committed changes in the repository (don't remember where).

Since I *knew* that I *committed* the changes in `R.cpp`, I chose **mine** to get the shelved version. But this **turned out to be wrong**.

Is there an explanation that helps to prevent future confusion?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> 
TortoiseSVN (1.14.*) provides a working shelving feature, [they explain](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-shelving.html):

> The shelving feature is still marked as experimental.
>
> That means that while shelving works as advertised, it is still in
> a stage where it's heavily improved and worked on. That also means
> that there's no guarantee that the shelves you create are upwards
> compatible and future versions might not be able to use them. And
> of course the UI might change as well in future versions to
> accommodate new features and behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shelving is best compared to interactions with some local repository.

Shelving is like committing changes in your working copy to the “shelf repo”
(and doing a revert after that).

Unshelving is like updating your working copy from the “shelf repo” that
contains earlier changes.

So *Theirs* always refers to the “shelf repo”. And *Mine* to the
current (and already committed) revision in your working copy.

To prevent the conflicts introduced by minor adjustments, you may revert
the changes of the last commit in `R.cpp` before unshelving.